# apt update failed: libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

When I run `sudo apt update`, I got:

```bash
$ sudo apt update
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Failed to fetch http://hwraid.le-vert.net/ubuntu/dists/precise/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/dists/focal-proposed/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://neurodeb.pirsquared.org/dists/data/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://neurodeb.pirsquared.org/dists/xenial/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It seems the `libp11-kit.so` is broken, I may fix the issue by installing the `libp11-kit-dev` again. But as the `apt update` does not work anymore, I don't know how to implement this. Or maybe there are any other solutions or suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I just realized the error is due to the broken libffi, I tried downloading the deb file from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libffi7_3.3-4_amd64.deb.html via
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi7_3.3-4_amd64.deb and installed it with `dpkg -i` and it works!

Comment: Hi I am getting same error, but this is not resolving my issue! (ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0)

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Show your log information for this? What't the result after you run `sudo dpkg -i xxx_amd64.deb`. Another way you need to take care is you should use the deb file for your own ubuntu version.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me either... I'm getting this show up when I'm trying to import the ParaView modules into a Python script.

Comment: @ShixiangWang installation command works fine. but error is not resolved.

Comment: use "conda install -c anaconda <package>" where package refers to the specific package that is throwing the error

Comment: I had the same problem and it's solved by downgrading python from 3.8.18 to 3.8.10 (conda install python=3.8.10 )

Comment: @SarveshThakur I was able to solve this problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with `rm ${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/libffi.7.so ${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/libffi.so.7` The problem is that those are dynamically linked to libffi8, which is incorrect.